# My 1 page web app reduces a variable by 2 instead of 1 after completing a certain level

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For some reason after the user guesses the right number and follows the confirm to play the game again but with fewer guesses (2 less than original), each time a user guesses a number the guesses remaining is deducted by 2 and sometimes just random numbers instead of the usual 1. I tried changing the code to deduct in various different ways but to no avail:

```
j--;
j -= 1;
j = j - 1;
```

Full code in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5dzt/),   if anyone could help that would be awesome I've been at this for hours! Thanks

partial for guess button click event

```
if (currentGuess < numberToGuess) { 
        $hintBox.html('<p class="blue">Try higher</p>');
        } else {
            $hintBox.html('<p class="blue">Go lower</p>');
                }
        j = j - 1;
        $('.numberGuesses').html(j);
}  // end of if guess is not correct

else if (currentGuess === numberToGuess) {
    alert('Well done the correct number was '+ numberToGuess);
  var playAgain = confirm("Let's see if you can do that again with less guesses.");
    if (playAgain){
        $('#gameDiv').hide('pulsate', 100, function(){
            $('#mode').delay(200).show('pulsate', 500);
        });
        lowerGuesses = lowerGuesses - 2;
        $('.numberGuesses').html(lowerGuesses);                
    } else { 
        location.reload();
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the fiddle, it seems to work just fine.

Comment: The Fiddle works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Using chrome and after first round bug appears.

Comment: Yh it only get's buggy after you get the guess right and press ok to the prompt

Answer (score 0):

You don't reset the counter `j` to `lowerGuesses` after you get the number right.

The code is very difficult to follow, and IMO a bit broken. Things need to be broken out much better. Isolate the "new game" code into something you call when there's actually a new game. Create a new random number. Clear out the numbers it remembers; after I fixed it it was the same number again (possible but unlikely, so I'm assuming that logic is also broken) so it both warned me that I'd already guess the number, *and* told me I guessed the number correctly.

Basically your game loop should be just for the game, not for preparing a new game, etc. Consider passing in the number of guesses the player should get into a `newGame` function (along with many other refactorings).

Comment: haha yh it's my first JavaScript project so I don't really know how to organise the code, I'm learning something new with each bug (which was the whole aim of the project). I guess I'm getting too ahead of myself as the code does work for the first round perfectly it's just going to the next level and setting the number of guesses allowed to 2 lower which spoils it.